# Unable to locate an existing element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using `Selenium` to get data from [this](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/europa-league/fc-copenhagen-stjarnan-hzwurDB2/#1X2;4) site and I encountered a problem that happen intermittently, I think this problem is related to the refresh of the page that the site runs every x seconds. Looking at the page of the link above I'm trying to get this table:

[image]

My code have have this design:

```
//Navigate to fixture page.
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/europa-league/fc-copenhagen-stjarnan-hzwurDB2/");

//Get all the available categories (eg: 1X2, AH, O/U etc...).
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("bettype-tabs-scope")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

//Get the tab 2nd Half.
var category = listItems.Where(li => li.Text == "2nd Half").SingleOrDefault();

//Click on the tab for load the table.
if (category != null)
{
   category.Click();
}
else
{
   //Tab doesn't exist, return an empty string.
   return string.Empty;
}

//Get the table.
var table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1]//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]"));
```

As I said this code works, but sometimes appear this error:

> : 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/europa-league/fc-copenhagen-stjarnan-hzwurDB2/#1X2;4)//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]"}
>     (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.84)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)'

I also tried to add an implicit wait after the click simulation:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

but this didn't fix the problem.

Someone know how can I handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried time.sleep() (I don't know C# syntax). I had a similar issue with Linkedin with selenium. The implicit/explicit waits wouldn't work (firewall I think) but the time.sleep worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some explicit wait after clicking the `2nd Half` link.Since,table loading is taking sometime.

**Modified Code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
//DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers NuGet package needs to be added
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1]//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]")));

//Get the table.
var table = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1]//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]"));

Console.WriteLine(table.Text);
```

**Output:**

```
 18bet  
-227
+225
+775
89.6%
```

**Edit:**

`ExpectedConditions` is deprecated from the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` and newly added in `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`. Please include the below NuGet Package

**NuGet Package Needs to be Added:**

```
DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

Expected Conditions will be available in both `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` and `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`.In order to avoid the conflicts, you can assign the newly imported package in one variable and can be access the required method.

So you can do the import like this ( `using SeleniumWaitHelper = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`; ) and `ExpectedConditions` can be accessed as  `SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions`

**Code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
//DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers NuGet package needs to be added
wait.Until(SeleniumWaitHelper.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1]//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]")));

//Get the table.
var table = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//table[contains(@class, 'table-main')])[1]//tbody//tr[normalize-space()]"));

Console.WriteLine(table.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your solution, for now the I didn't get any errors, just a question: `ExpectedConditions` seems deprecated, I'm not able to find the replacement method, isn't implemented yet? You know when will be implemented?

Comment: @Charanoglu:ExpectedConditions is deprecated from the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI and newly added in SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers. Please check the edited answer